# Function being activated without changes in the worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created this script so that a bot in the Telegram sends a message to my channel, in "body" I put to copy the data of the cell A4, that way, when something changes in cell A4 the bot triggers a message in my telegram containing the new values.

```
function sendTelegramNotification(botSecret, chatId, body) {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendMessage?text=" + encodeURIComponent(body) + "&chat_id=" + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
}
```

What is happening is that when the worksheet is open, it actually does not send anything if the A4 cell does not change its values. However, when the worksheet is closed, it sends the same messages every 10 to 15 minutes, even if nothing has changed in the A4 cell.

I need some help to find out how I can not do this anymore and even with the spreadsheet closed, just send a message if the A4 cell really changes the values.

Comment: There is no trigger available to scripts that fires when A4 changes it's value unless a user changes it's value.

Comment: @Cooper But when the spreadsheet is closed, the bot sends the same messages even though nothing has been edited in the A4 cell.

That I do not understand why it happens.

Comment: I don't know sounds like a bot problem.

Comment: @Cooper I also thought that could be a problem with the bot. But when the worksheet is open, everything is perfect.

The problem happens when the worksheet is closed. Then it shows that it is something in the worksheet that activates the created function even though nothing has been edited.

I'll wait and see if by chance someone appears to have any help. Let's hope.

Comment: Try changing the name of `sendTelegramNotification` to `onEdit`, but as @Cooper said, triggers only work when a user edits a value, never from an API call.